# ObjectAL on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, ios7, openal

I've been using ObjectAL 2.2 for a while on iOS 6 without any problems BUT in iOS 7, I get this:

```
OAL Error: +[ALWrapper createContext:attributes:]: Invalid Value (error code 0x0000a004)
OAL Warning: -[OALAudioSession onAudioError:]: Received audio error notification, but last reset was 0.000820 seconds ago. Doing nothing.
OAL Error: +[ALWrapper genSources:numSources:]: Invalid Operation (error code 0x0000a004)
OAL Warning: -[OALAudioSession onAudioError:]: Received audio error notification, but last reset was 0.001542 seconds ago. Doing nothing.
OAL Error: +[ALWrapper getSourcef:parameter:]: Invalid Value (error code 0x0000a003)
OAL Warning: -[OALAudioSession onAudioError:]: Received audio error notification, but last reset was 0.002222 seconds ago. Doing nothing.
```

I have tried the 'bleeding edge' version too but it has the same issues. What can be done to fix the problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem only in the iOS 7 simulator but on the actual device, there are no more errors.